# What is that maximum-size when we can talk about "mobile" device?

Tags: html, css, mobile

so, I want to do a "mobile" friend view of my site. Its liquid designed already, but mobiles need definitely different look. Now, how to detect if I visited it with mobile (iphone, ipad, android)? More specifically, I imagine it as if the screen width is smaller than a value (dunno that value), then thats considered a mobile client. How to detect, so that generate the mobile optimized CSS/HTML outputs? Maybe im too simple, but to me mobile client = smaller screen, and nothing more

Comment: "mobile client = smaller screen, and nothing more" - not so. Different input methods, different bandwidth capabilities, different UI paradigms. Not to mention that most mobile devices have high-density displays, higher than even the (current) best desktop/laptop displays.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a great way. Before you used to be able to say if under a certain number of pixels then it is a phone. But now phones are getting both higher pixel count but also crucially large screens too. Tablets are as small as 7" now, but they could get smaller. Some phones are over 5" and could get bigger. Then there are things like physical pixels to css pixel ratios to think about.

If not screen size or pixel count, maybe it could be if it supports touch or not. But Windows 8 threw that on its head, as that supports touch on the desktop.

I would say it depends on the content rather than the device. Test your site using various widths. See when the width becomes sub-optimal for the content, and throw in a media query there to adapt the layout. I think a content first rather than device first strategy is more future proof.

Also remember that it may not just be a mobile that wants your mobile friendly layout. For example soemone could be using their browser in a small window, rather than full screen, or they could be using the snap mode in Windows 8, where the width is the same as a iPhone width at 320px.

Comment: aham. So, all I wanted to switch CSS/HTML based on current width, but thats not gonna work that way, right? The better way is put a link "check our site in mobile" and made design for that? Im noob at mobile devices anyway.

Comment: you can change CSS via media queries at a specific width (or height or many other things) but not HTML. You can hide HTML with display: none; though. The main problem is what is the specific width you should use. It generally depends on the content rather than the device. I wouldn't say add a link to switch to a different site entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Use media queries. Then you can detect if you are on a mobile device the browser will load the mobile CSS and if you are on a PC the browser will load the PC version of the CSS.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Then you can develop the mobile device CSS like this way (supose the mobile have 480x640 pixels):

```
@media screen and (max-device-width:480px){
    ...
    put your mobile device CSS code here
    ...
}
```

Supose you want develop CSS for tablets (1.024x768pixels)

```
@media screen and (max-device-width:1024px) and (orientation:portrait){
    ...
    put your tablet device CSS code here when tablet has portrait orientation. 
    ...
}

@media screen and (max-device-width:1024px) and (orientation:landscape){
    ...
    put your tablet device CSS code here when tablet has landscape orientation. 
    ...
}
```

And for PCs (1280x968pixels):

```
@media screen and (max-device-width:1280px){
    ...
    put your PC CSS code here
    ...
}
```

Comment: except mobile devices could be more than 480px wide (and it is not really recommended to use max-device-width, as that is the screen size not the viewport of the browser. See for example http://tech.bluesmoon.info/2011/01/device-width-and-how-not-to-hate-your.html ), and desktop may benefit from some of the mobile friendly styles if it has a touch browser (Win 8 and devices like the Google Pixel). There is no real bulletproof way.

Comment: yeah its true... there is not a "nice" solution but my solution is better than take only one CSS for all devices isn't it ^^ ?

Comment: I'd use max-width rather than max-device-width, and be careful not to design the width just around the iPhone width. You might even want a smaller query for more feature phone sized screens as content often breaks when that small width. I'd still set the breakpoints where the content needs it, rather than a specific width of a certain devices.